# Django Post request not sent on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

i am new to Django, I am trying to create simple web page which sends ajax request when button is clicked. But post request is not sent
template

```
<form action="" method="post" id="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
  <select id="select_dropdown">
  <option value="joshua">joshua</option>
  <option value="peter">peter</option>
  </select>
<input type="button" method = "POST" value="Apply" id="submitme" name="submitme">

</form>.
 <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.4.1.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <script language="JavaScript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#submitme').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var p = document.getElementById("select_dropdown");
    var value = p.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        type: "post", // or "get"
        data: value,
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, // for csrf token
        success: function(data) {
             window.location.replace("/video_courses/");
            alert(data.result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

view.py

```
 if request.method == "POST":  # os request.GET()
        print("inside post")
        get_value = request.body

        data = {}
        data['result'] = 'you made a request'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Please help

Comment: Did you try changing `method="post"` to `method="POST"` in the form?